# Asp.net Range Validator

Tags: asp.net, rangevalidator

**Html (Full Code)**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSasiNo" runat="server" Width="250px" MaxLength="17"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator CssClass="zorunlu" ValidationGroup="kaskoTeklifSayfasi" Display="Dynamic" ID="rangevalidator1" runat="server" SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="txtSasiNo" ErrorMessage="Enter number characters only (8 or 17)" ValidationExpression="^\d{8}$|^\d{17}$""></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvSasiNo" SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="kaskoTeklifSayfasi" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtSasiNo" CssClass="zorunlu">Please enter Number.</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

**Question:**

I am trying to use RangeValidator.

**If txtnumber is null or empty and if txtnumber is not 8 characters or not 17 characters**.
Only 2 options first option is 8 character second option is 17 character.

**txtnumber** text character only can be like below

```
12345678    // This is 8 characters
12345678901234567    // This is 17 characters
```

What to add to RangeValidator in order to achieve this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described by [Ondrej](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2440262/ondrej-svejdar) you can use `RegularExpressionValidator`. To be more specific with the aspx. See the code below:-

UPDATED CODE:

Here you go:-

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtnumber" runat="server" Width="250px"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator Display="Dynamic" ID="regtxt" runat="server" SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="txtnumber" ErrorMessage="Enter number characters only (8 or 17)" 
    ValidationExpression="^\d{8}$|^\d{17}$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Don't use range validator - use regex validator instead:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ValidationExpression="^([0-9]{8})|([0-9]{17})$" ... />
```

Comment: Hello thanks for answer however it is not working for 17 any idea please ?

Answer (score 0):

The validators usually ignore empty fields. Notable exception: the RequiredFieldValidator. Add that to guard against empty fields and keep the RangeValidator to force a specific range of values.